# Can I run a while loop in the background at the same time as other things?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm making a game a bit like cookie clicker, using Tinter. But I need to have a while True loop to make the money keep going up, but at the same time the user needs to be able to click the buttons and buy investments, and most importantly click on the button. Is there a way to do this?

```
from tkinter import *
import time
import tkinter
top = tkinter.Tk()
balance       = 0
balmultiplier = 0
wishwells     = 0

def clickmain():
    global balance
    global balmultiplier
    balance += 5 + balmultiplier
    Number.config()
buttonmain =  tkinter.Button(top, text ="Click here!", command =        clickmain)



def buywishwell():
    global balance
    global wishwells
    global balmultiplier
    if balance >= 100 + (wishwells * 2):
        balance -= 100 + (wishwells * 2)
        wishwells += 1
        balmultiplier += 5
        print("\nYou have purchased a Wishing Well!\n")
    else:
        print("\nYou can't afford that..\n")

mb=  Menubutton ( top, text="Investments")
mb.grid()
mb.menu  =  Menu ( mb, tearoff = 0 )
mb["menu"]  =  mb.menu

mb.menu.add_checkbutton (label="Wishing Well - £"+str(100 +  (wishwells * 2)), command=buywishwell)


info      = Message( top, text="Purchases:\n Wishing Wells:   "+str(wishwells) )
balvisual = Message( top, text="Your balance is "+str(balance))
mb.pack()
buttonmain.pack()
balvisual.pack()
info.pack()
top.mainloop()
```

Comment: Did you check https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html

Comment: @itzmeontv: in this case, threading is completely unnecessary and adds considerable complexity.